# Comparing pre and post treatment data - best statistical test?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance, descriptive-statistics, excel

I am analysing a range of clinical outcomes for a drug treatment and need to compare the values pre and post treatment - I’m using excel to do this and have found that for most of my outcomes the data is not normally distributed. Sample size is 69 patients - as such id imagine I’m best presenting my results as median and IQR but just wondering what stat test is best to run? Doing this in excel.

Comment: Depending on what’s the aim, a paired t-test or paired Wilcoxon test may be enough.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Choose your test]

I typically reference one of these. Save the ol' brain power for the programs.

Comment: That chart fails to account for the fact that nonparametric methods and semiparametric (ordinal) regressions work great for quantitative Y.

Comment: For the original question I'd use the [rank difference test](https://hbiostat.org/bbr/nonpar#sec-nonpar-rd).

Comment: Definitely, definitely agree with both of you. May I follow up with ad additional parametric/nonparametric flowchart? Or should I replace the first for the complete thought process?

Comment: I recommend started a new chart that recognizes that an interval-scaled Y is also ordinal and that nonparametric/semiparametric methods are fully efficient.  Semiparametric models can also estimate differences in means/quantiles.  And models contain tests as special cases; separate tests not needed.  See https://hbiostat.org/bbr/nonpar and https://fharrell.com/post/rpo